# Masstransit Not Handling Correct Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, masstransit

I´m playing with MassTransit with a simple example and I don´t know what I´m doing wrong, because I don´t receive the correct data.
I have a simple asp.net-mvc app with the following code in the HomeController

```
public class TweetCreatedCommand : Command
{
    public readonly string Message;
    public readonly DateTime Timestamp;
    public readonly Guid TweetId;
    public readonly string Who;

    public TweetCreatedCommand(Guid tweetId, string message, DateTime timeStamp, string who)
    {
        TweetId = tweetId;
        Message = message;
        Timestamp = timeStamp;
        Who = who;
    }
}

public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TweetCreatedCommand data;

        Bus.Initialize(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseMsmq();
            sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
            sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/test_queue");
            sbc.Subscribe(subs =>
            {
                subs.Handler<TweetCreatedCommand>(msg => data = new TweetCreatedCommand(msg.TweetId, msg.Message,msg.Timestamp,msg.Who));
            });
        });

        Bus.Instance.Publish(new TweetCreatedCommand(Guid.NewGuid(),"foo!",DateTime.Now,"CDA"));

                    ViewData.Model = data;

        return View();
    }
```

If I debug this code, I can see how the TweetCreatedCommand is published and the data is OK in the MSMQ queue, but when the handler receives the data: 
TweetCreatedCommand.TweetId is: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 and it should be other thing
TweetCreatedCommand.Message is null and it should be "foo!"
TweetCreatedCommand.TimeStamp is 01/01/01
Who is null and it should be "CDA"

What is wrong??

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit's default serialization only works on properties. Try changing your readonly fields to properties and the serializer should populate the data correctly. If readonly fields are required, change to the `BinarySerializer` (default is JSON).

Comment: Thank you so much, now it works perfectly changing the readonly fields

Comment: If I try with UseBinarySerializer it isn´t working. It calls the TweetCreatedCommand constructor when it publishes, but It doesn´t call the constructor again after the publish so the variable data is null.

Comment: Bring this up on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/masstransit-discuss ; I haven't used the BinarySerializer myself for any reason, I'm sure there's some additional gotchas around it that just aren't coming to mind. Additionally, check out the specs: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/master/src/MassTransit.Tests/Serialization most of then run for each serializer.